# Two MSI Z270 SLI PLUS have different graphic output quality (BIOS mod?)

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios, intel-core-i7

I have two `MSI Z270 SLI PLUS` motherboards with intent to install matching hardware /software configuration.  Unfortunately, they are not identical:  one has BIOS `E7A59IMS.140` from `12/15/2016`, the other - `E7A59IZ1.1J1` from `07/06/2017`:

[image: v.140]
[image: v.1J1]

First puzzle: [current highest official BIOS version](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z270-SLI-PLUS) is `7A59v1A` from `2018-07-17`.
M-Flash recognizes `E7A59IMS.1A0` file on the first mobo (`14`), but not on the second.  I attribute that to `1A` being less than `1J`, but **would like to have a confirmation**.
Even so, *i can't explain dates being out of order*.

Googling `E7A59IZ1.1J1` results in only two links, https://bios.ethosdistro.com/motherboard-bios/current-bios-list.txt and a related direct file URL.  So, this may not be an official BIOS?
**Is there a way to re-flash `1J` to official one (`1A`)**?

Both sets (`mobo + cpu + ram`) have passed rigorous (24+ hrs) `MemTest86 v7.3`.

---

Next, Windows setup (from the same USB drive) looks normal on `14`:
[image: v.140]

but has dithered color depth on `1J`:
[image: v.1J1]
and lower resolution (dialog fills entire screen):
[image: v.1J1]
occasionally with color (and in Classic theme!):
[image: v.1J1]

Since CPU graphics is used on both, **is this a result of BIOS mod on `1J`, or 2nd CPU is somehow damaged**?  (I thought about swapping CPUs, but haven't gotten to it yet, will try next)

---

**2019-May-03**
Swapped CPUs, **the problem remains on `1J`**.
So it seems to be a result of some BIOS mod (possibly from|by|for `ethOS`?)..

Would love to re-flash it with official `1A` BIOS, but `1J`'s M-Flash does not recognize the file..

Wiped a 256MB USB 2.0 stick, copied a single 16MB `E7A59IMS.1A0` file to it:
[image: 7A59v1A]
**`1J` refuses to see/recognize the update**:
[image: 1J]
while `14` is perfectly happy recognizing it (also added sub-folders with drivers):
[image: 14]

**Is there any other way to force flashing of official `1A` BIOS over this suspect `1J`?**

Comment: This could be caused by several things.  Switching the CPUs would eliminate that possible cause.  If these motherboards are under warranty I would see if you could replace the motherboard with the weird firmware loaded.  *It's actually not uncommon for a motherboard to have a firmware that isn't published by an OEM.*  You might also have a slightly different revision of the hardware, even if it's the same motherboard, so a different firmware might make sense.  I would either try to roll back to `7A59v19` or contact MSI for any support options that might exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted [this same question on MSI forum](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=318723.0).  Extremely happy to receive help from gurus!  Thank you!!
The solution was to force flash proper official BIOS, all details are spelled out and illustrated.